# How to inject dependencies over ios UIViewControllers

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uiviewcontroller, dependency-injection

Assuming I have an instance of an NSObject that I create in the appDelegate, what is the easiest possibility to make this instance available to some of my UIViewControllers.

I know different approaches, but they all don't really satisfy my needs

1. **Delegation**
   I could define a protocol (`MHSomeObjectDataSource`) and let the AppDelegate implement it.
2. **Hold properties** on UIViewControllers (`MSSomeObject`) and always set it after instantiation of the UIViewControllers
3. **Making the object a singleton** Nope for many reasons

My main problem with 1,2 is  that I always have to make sure manually that the property / delegate is set.

Is there a convenient way for dependency injection that I don't know about yet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of options, maybe one of them is a good fit for you:

- If you create your controllers programmatically you can use constructor based injection and pass these dependencies as required parameters of a designated initializer.
- If you don't mind having a singleton or otherwise globally accessible IoC container or dependency factory you could use a subclass to trigger injection in `awakeFromNib` or in designated initializers..
- Similarly you can subclass `UIStoryboard` to override `instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier` and inject dependencies into view controllers (again assuming there's a good way for the storyboard to get them in the first place).
- If you're working with objective-c or obj-c compatible types you might benefit from existing DI frameworks like http://objection-framework.org/ or 
  http://typhoonframework.org/.

I think https://www.objc.io/issues/15-testing/dependency-injection/ is a nice discussion of approaches as well.